# Unable to uninstall python: appears on cmd but not on control panel

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I wanted to make a clean installation of python. I noticed I had 2 versions installed (both py --version and python --version showed me different versions) at the same time, so I decided to uninstall both.

I went to the control panel apps, and it only showed one of them. Uninstalled it. Went back to cmd, and python --version still provides me a version (py-- version doesn't anymore).

So, how do I uninstall it?

Comment: `$(Get-Command python).source` in PowerShell will show you the path to the executable.

Comment: `where python` in `cmd` will show the same.

Comment: @Friedrich Ok, it does, but it delivers 3 different outputs. 1 folder (on cygwin64 folder), and two executables (on msys64 folder, and on AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps). Now what do I do?

Comment: I would guess it shows the executable files called "python" in you `PATH` variable. The first one is the one that will be started if you call just `python`. Obviously, you have cygwin installed and its version of Python. Edit your `PATH` and make sure cygwin's bin is at the end so it doesn't shadow any other Python.

Comment: @Friedrich Ok, but, how do I uninstall the python version that appears on cmd?

Comment: The one from cygwin: by uninstalling cygwin. The one from msys64: same. The one in AppData/Local/whatever actually opens Microsoft Store to let you install Python from there. It's not a problem to have several versions installed as long as you know which one you're using.

Comment: @Friedrich as far as I understand, I'm using msys64 python whenever I use "pip install something". And, the thing is, I'm not being able to install certain things, such as numpy and opcua. But I was able to install robotframework. Any idea why? It just says: exit code 1, and a that its an error from a subprocess (and not from pip)

Comment: Open a question with the exact command you are trying to run and the full error message including traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python *is* installed, but through MSYS MINGW64.

If I want to install Python in my system, I can, but I just have to make sure to reference it later by `py` and not by `python` in the cmd.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows and installed Python via the Microsoft Store, you should uninstall your version there as well.

Have you tried this command?
-> pip uninstall python

Comment: pip cannot uninstall (or install) Python

Comment: that command doesn't work. Moreover, that command tells me that there is no installation of python